# How to set AutoLayout constraint of UIimageView with UIButton?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, autolayout

This tree include the cicle is a UIImageView's image, but the text in the circle is a UIButton. When the device is changed, like iPhone5 change to iPhone6 Plus, the image with scale to big. The Button always move to the circle's outSide. How to Solve the problem?

[image: Image Here]

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout has a feature called propotion. It means that by selecting any 2 UI objects you can set propotion between them for any constraint such as width, height, etc.. In tour case also select imageview and button then move to the constraints view, double click on any objects width constraint i.e either button width or image width. There you can find a option called propotion. As per your requirement you want to have a button always inside the image view, means that buttom propotion should be less than the imageview propotion. So you can set 2:3, means button width is 2/3rd part of the imageview. Now button will be always part of the imageview irrespective of the device which you run.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add proportional width and height constraints to your buttons relative to imageView like this screenshot

[image]

Here I have not added fixed height and width constraints to imageview, because image view takes width and height from its content i.e from image provided to it, if you want to fix height and width of image view then you can provide those too.